# measure mountain height from the top using triangulation

Tags: geometry, triangles, triangulation

We know how to measure the height of a mountain from the ground using triangulation:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_of_triangles

The question is how to do same from the top of the mountain.

Formally: from the top T of a mountain looking down to a straight road on the ground with 3 mile markers A B C.  Given AB = BC = 1 miles and two angles ATB and BTC.  Calculate the distance TB, or equivalently the height of T.

Need a formula that can be implemented by a program.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the road run straight away from the mountain?

Comment: not necessarily, but you can make that assumption if it helps to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the following diagram, the key to the problem is to find $\theta$ in terms of x and y.

[image]

It should be clear that the areas of the three shaded triangles are the same. Then, $pq \sin y = qr \sin x$. This means $\dfrac {p}{r} = \dfrac {\sin x}{\sin y}$.

In $\triangle TAC$, $\dfrac {p}{r} = \dfrac {\sin (\pi – ((x + y) + \theta)}{\sin \theta}$.

Then, $\dfrac {\sin x}{\sin y} = \dfrac {\sin ((x + y) + \theta)}{\sin \theta}$.  From which, $\theta$ can be found.

Comment: Voila.  Thanks Mick for a great solution.

Comment: If you think that is a solution, you should accept it by ticking it.